# Problemas con Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger, transacciones

El siguiente código me devuelve un error y la vdd no sé como solucionarlo.

la subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor, lo que no es correcto cuando va a continuación de =, !=, <, <=, >, >= o cuando se utiliza como expresión

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[depositos_deduccion]
   ON [dbo].[Depositos] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @dato real,
        @cuota money,
        @saldo money,   
        @AP money,
        @meses_deduce int,
        @SP money

BEGIN TRAN pago_prestamo

        DECLARE @id_cliente int = (SELECT Id_Cliente FROM Depositos inserted)
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Detalle_Prestamos WHERE Id_Cliente = @id_cliente)
        BEGIN

        PRINT ' Se ha realizado una deducción a la deuda del cliente con la cooperativa '
        
        DECLARE cursor1 cursor for
        SELECT Tasa_Interes_Anual, Cuota_Prestamo, Saldo_Prestamo FROM Detalle_Prestamos D INNER JOIN Prestamos P ON D.Id_Prestamo = P.Id_Prestamo AND Id_Cliente = @id_cliente
        open cursor1 
        fetch cursor1 into @dato, @cuota, @saldo 
        while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        begin 
        
        SET @AP = @cuota - (@saldo/12)*(@dato/100)
        SET @saldo = @saldo - @AP

        UPDATE Detalle_Prestamos SET Meses_Restantes_Prestamo = Meses_Prestamo - 1 , Abono_Prestamo = @AP, Saldo_Prestamo = @saldo WHERE Id_Cliente = @id_cliente 
        
        PRINT @AP
        PRINT @saldo

        fetch cursor1 into @dato, @cuota, @saldo
end
        close cursor1
        deallocate cursor1
        COMMIT TRAN pago_prestamo
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRAN pago_prestamo
        END
END
GO
```

Comment: Te está diciendo que la sub-consulta devuelve más de un valor, podrías contar los registros, pues al parecer lo que quieres es verificar si existen datos con ese criterio. Ponlo así y prueba: **`IF EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Detalle_Prestamos WHERE Id_Cliente = @id_cliente)`**

Comment: a esta consulta no le falta un where? SELECT Id_Cliente FROM Depositos inserted

Comment: @A.Cedano ya hice la prueba pero me sale el mismo error...

Comment: @gbianchi se supone que no porque el inserted es del parámetro que esta recibiendo

Comment: ah perdon no habia visto eso.. esto es sql server? si es asi, agrega ese tag...

Comment: Para poder ayudarte y mejorar la forma y lógica del trigger, deberías de pegar la estructura de las tablas `depósitos`, `prestamos` y `detalle_prestamos`, o al menos una pequeña muestra de sus columnas y como enlazan entre ellas. El primer error es porque el trigger es `(Declare @id_cliente int = (SELECT Top(1) inserted.Id_Cliente FROM  inserted ))`; Pero aunque funcione no es correcto porque desde la lógica de conjuntos a esta tabla se le pueden realizar varias inserciones para múltiples clientes a la vez.

Answer (score 2):

El problema seguramente es esto:

```
DECLARE @id_cliente int = (SELECT Id_Cliente FROM Depositos inserted)
```

estas recuperando la tabla completa `Depositos`, si esta tabla tiene al menos dos filas ya obtienes el error, por que la asignación de variables espera siempre un único valor. NOTA: el `inserted` al final solo funciona como una alias de tabla.

Imagino que lo que buscas es algo así:

```
DECLARE @id_cliente int = (SELECT Id_Cliente FROM inserted)
```

O al menos es lo que puedo deducir de la lógica y tus comentarios, es decir leer el `Id_Cliente` de la fila recién insertada.

#### Importante

Hay un tema conceptual de los triggers en SQL Server que lamentablemente veo que no está suficientemente claro, o al menos no se llega a comprender del todo. Los triggers son eventos que se disparan ante ciertas situaciones, en este caso una inserción, pero la inserción puede corresponder a una sola fila o a múltiples. Si eventualmente estuvieras insertando varios `Depositos`, el trigger se ejecutará una sola vez, con lo cual aún esta correción:

```
DECLARE @id_cliente int = (SELECT Id_Cliente FROM inserted)
```

Fallará sin duda. Podrías evitar esto si solo obtienes un único valor:

```
DECLARE @id_cliente int = (SELECT TOP 1 Id_Cliente FROM inserted)
```

pero, el siguiente problema, es lo que ocurre si un día se hace una inserción masiva de depósitos de múltiples clientes, y aquí el problema será peor, por que el trigger no fallará pero toda la lógica es dependiente de una inserción atada a un único cliente. Todo esto te lo comento por que si quieres hacer las cosas bien tendrías que optar por dos estrategias 1) Modificar la lógica del trigger asumiendo la posibilidad de múltiples filas y múltiples clientes 2) Controlar e invalidar el trigger con un error si se intenta insertar depositos de más de un cliente.

Nota: Ya sé, lo que digo no puede pasar, as la aplicación la que solo puede insertar de un depósito a la vez y siempre es de un mismo cliente, pero lo cierto es "que si algo puede pasar (y si encima es malo) seguramente pasará"

Answer (score -1):

**Les agradezco a todos la ayuda, se soluciono con un top 1, adjunto código por si alguno pasa por el mismo problema que yo.**

```
Use [cooperativa_solidarista];
Go

/*******************************************************************************************
***** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[depositos_deduccion]    Script Date: 10/04/2021 19:32:18 *****
*******************************************************************************************/

Set Ansi_Nulls On;
Go

Set Quoted_Identifier On;
Go

Alter Trigger dbo.depositos_deduccion On dbo.depositos
After Insert
As
    Begin
        Begin Tran pago_prestamo;
        Declare @Dato         Real
              , @Cuota        Money
              , @Saldo        Money
              , @Ap           Money
              , @Meses_Deduce Int
              , @Sp           Money;
        Declare @Id_Cliente Int = (
                                    Select Top 1 id_cliente
                                           From depositos As inserted
                                  );
        If Exists (
                    Select *
                           From detalle_prestamos
                           Where id_cliente = @Id_Cliente
                  ) 
        Begin
            Print ' Se ha realizado una deducción a la deuda del cliente con la cooperativa ';
            Declare cursor1 Cursor
            For Select tasa_interes_anual
                     , cuota_prestamo
                     , saldo_prestamo
                     , meses_restantes_prestamo
                       From detalle_prestamos As d
                          , prestamos As p
                       Where d.id_prestamo = p.id_prestamo And id_cliente = @Id_Cliente;
            Open cursor1;
            Fetch cursor1 Into @Dato
                             , @Cuota
                             , @Saldo
                             , @Meses_Deduce;
            While @@Fetch_Status = 0
            Begin
                Set @Ap = @Cuota - (@Saldo / 12) * @Dato / 100;
                Set @Saldo = @Saldo - @Ap;
                Set @Meses_Deduce = @Meses_Deduce - 1;
                Update detalle_prestamos
                       Set meses_restantes_prestamo = @Meses_Deduce
                         , abono_prestamo = @Ap
                         , saldo_prestamo = @Saldo
                Where id_cliente = @Id_Cliente;
                Print @Ap;
                Print @Saldo;
                Print @Dato;
                Print @Meses_Deduce;
                Set @Saldo = 0;
                Set @Ap = 0;
                Set @Meses_Deduce = 0;
                Fetch cursor1 Into @Dato
                                 , @Cuota
                                 , @Saldo
                                 , @Meses_Deduce;
        End;
            Close cursor1;
            Deallocate cursor1;
            Commit Tran pago_prestamo;
        End;
        Else
        Begin
            RollBack Tran pago_prestamo;
        End;
    End;
```

Comment: Esto efectivamente _soluciona_ el que aparezca un error al ejecutar el alter trigger, pero la lógica está rota, te recomiendo leer de nuevo la excelente [respuesta de Patricio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/442957/21).