# Update con cursores en sql server

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Tengo un cursor que esta actualizando los mismos datos para ambas filas, de las dos tablas, adjunto pantallazos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al insertar los datos todo sale tal y como debería ser pero al dispararse el trigger y recorrer la tabla con el cursor para actualizar sucede lo siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver los días se rebajan igual el abono del préstamo aunque debería ser diferente para ambos prestamos es el mismo y el saldo del préstamo es el mismo para ambos prestamos

```
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[depositos_deduccion]    Script Date: 
10/04/2021 19:32:18 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[depositos_deduccion]
   ON [dbo].[Depositos] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

BEGIN TRAN pago_prestamo

DECLARE @dato real,
        @cuota money,
        @saldo money,   
        @AP money,
        @meses_deduce int,
        @SP money
    DECLARE @id_cliente int = (SELECT TOP 1 Id_Cliente FROM Depositos inserted)
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Detalle_Prestamos WHERE Id_Cliente = @id_cliente)
    BEGIN

    PRINT ' Se ha realizado una deducción a la deuda del cliente con la cooperativa '
    
    DECLARE cursor1 cursor for
    SELECT Tasa_Interes_Anual, Cuota_Prestamo, Saldo_Prestamo, Meses_Restantes_Prestamo FROM Detalle_Prestamos D, Prestamos P WHERE D.Id_Prestamo = P.Id_Prestamo AND Id_Cliente = @id_cliente
    open cursor1 
    fetch cursor1 into @dato, @cuota, @saldo, @meses_deduce  
    while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    begin 
    
    
    SET @AP = @cuota - (@saldo/12)*(@dato/100)
    SET @saldo = @saldo - @AP
    SET @meses_deduce = @meses_deduce - 1

    UPDATE Detalle_Prestamos SET Meses_Restantes_Prestamo = @meses_deduce, Abono_Prestamo = @AP, Saldo_Prestamo = @saldo WHERE Id_Cliente = @id_cliente

    
    PRINT @AP
    PRINT @saldo
    PRINT @dato
    PRINT @meses_deduce


    SET @saldo = 0
    SET @AP = 0
    SET @meses_deduce = 0

    fetch cursor1 into @dato, @cuota, @saldo, @meses_deduce
    end
    close cursor1
    deallocate cursor1
    
    COMMIT TRAN pago_prestamo
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRAN pago_prestamo
    END

    END
```

Agradezco de antemano la ayuda que me puedan brindar

Comment: Considero que si lees con atención la [respuesta a tu otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/442957/21) tienes lo necesario para comprender cuál es el problema y cómo resolverlo.

Comment: Entiendo @jachguate hay una forma en que pueda actualizar diferentes filas asociadas a un solo ID ???

Answer (score 0):

**Buenas colegas, al final si pude hacerlo, al recorrer el ID registro, adjunto el código y evidencias por si alguien pasa por el mismo problema**

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[depositos_deduccion]
ON [dbo].[Depositos]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

BEGIN TRAN pago_prestamo

DECLARE @dato real,
@cuota money,
@saldo money,
@AP money,
@meses_deduce int,
@SP money,
@idRegi int

```
    DECLARE @id_cliente int = (SELECT TOP 1 Id_Cliente FROM Depositos inserted)
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Detalle_Prestamos WHERE Id_Cliente = @id_cliente)
    BEGIN

    PRINT ' Se ha realizado una deducción a la deuda del cliente con la cooperativa '
    
    DECLARE cursor1 cursor for
    SELECT  Id_Registro, Tasa_Interes_Anual, Cuota_Prestamo, Saldo_Prestamo, Meses_Restantes_Prestamo FROM Detalle_Prestamos D, Prestamos P WHERE D.Id_Prestamo = P.Id_Prestamo AND Id_Cliente = @id_cliente
    open cursor1 
    fetch cursor1 into @idRegi, @dato, @cuota, @saldo, @meses_deduce  
    while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    begin 
    

    
    SET @AP = @cuota - (@saldo/12)*(@dato/100)
    SET @saldo = @saldo - @AP
    SET @meses_deduce = @meses_deduce - 1

    

    UPDATE Detalle_Prestamos SET Meses_Restantes_Prestamo = @meses_deduce, Abono_Prestamo = @AP, Saldo_Prestamo = @saldo WHERE Id_Cliente = @id_cliente AND Id_Registro = @idRegi


    fetch cursor1 into @idRegi, @dato, @cuota, @saldo, @meses_deduce
    end
    close cursor1
    deallocate cursor1
    
    COMMIT TRAN pago_prestamo
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRAN pago_prestamo
    END

    END
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]